# Restraining mobile number input

Tags: html, mobile, input, restrictions

I have a form where I am accepting mobile number from users. Condition is that, I have to accept only the numbers starting from either 7, 8, or 9 and max length should be ten. I am using the following code for the same :

```
<input name="wno" id="wno" type="number" placeholder="Whats App No." required="required" minlength="10" maxlength="10" style="border-color:black" pattern = "/(7|8|9)\d{9}/">
```

But still the both the conditions are failing :

1) starting from 7, 8, or 9 &
2) max length should be 10.

Please guide me. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern attribute works with the following input types: `text, date, search, url, tel, email, and password`.

Your input type is `number` so the pattern is ignored.

Change your input type to `text` or `tel` and it will work as expected.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Thanks for the input Darren, it solves the length woe perfectly, but now its not  the solving the starting digit woe. Its not accepting the numbers starting from 7,8 and 9. I changed the type to tel.

Comment: You need to remove the leading and trailing slashes